# Etymology of Persian سبز (sabz), meaning "green"

Tags: historical-linguistics

Where does سبز come from? ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%B3%D8%A8%D8%B2#Persian) has no etymological information.) Urdu and Hindhi have the word "sabzi", which is derived from it, but is there a PIE root from which this derives, or is Old Persian the furthest back we can trace it?

Comment: Why are some people trying to close this excellent question?

Comment: @Fdb in what way does it related to the study of linguistic systems? This is a philology question, not a linguistics question.

Comment: @curiousdannii. It is about Indo-European etymology, a core discipline within linguistics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The origin of sabz is debated. One suggestion is that it derives from Iranian *spar “to blossom, to sprout”, and is thus cognate with Latin spargo, English sprig etc. The derivation is phonologically complex. If you have access to a university library look up the complicated argumentation by W.B. Henning, Bulletin of the School of Oriental and African Studies, 1947, pp. 46 (bottom) to 47, (also in his Collected papers, vol. 2, pp. 280-1).

Comment: Also here on jstor: https://www.jstor.org/stable/608983?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: Thanks, was able to see more on JSTOR